# Variable $input of type ScriptTagInput! was provided invalid value

Tags: javascript, api, graphql, shopify

How to correctly do a mutation inside a JS file?

Here is my query inside my JS file currently:

```
    const src = "https://faqapp.test/scripttags/app.js";

                axios({
                    url: "/app/graphql",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        query: `mutation scriptTagCreate($input: ScriptTagInput!) {
                            scriptTagCreate(input: $input) {
                              scriptTag {
                                id
                              }
                              userErrors {
                                field
                                message
                              }
                            }
                          }`,
                        variables: {
                            input: {
                                src
                            }
                        },
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        }
                    }
                })
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res.data);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err.message);
                    });
```

And the query i am trying to perform (which works in the graphql explorer):

```
  mutation scriptTagCreate($input: ScriptTagInput!) {
    scriptTagCreate(input: $input) {
     scriptTag {
       id
     }
     userErrors {
       field
       message
     }
  }
}
```

Query Variables

```
{
  "input": {
    "src": "https://faqapp.test/createbannertemplate.js"
  }
}
```

I'm new to graphql so there might be something really simple I am missing.
This is more a shopify app i am developing.

Thanks, hopefully this wasn't too vague.

Comment: You don't need to have `headers` inside of `data`. Please place it outside and try to run it.

Comment: Still the same error, even with the headers outside of data

Comment: not the same `src` arg/variable - criteria of valid src arg? ... compare network requests ... different auth reasons?

Comment: Also try putting the complete GQL url path.

Answer (score 0):

pass src value as below.

```
input: {
     src: src
}
```